# access to import statement from within __init__.py (or how to not run __init__.py when importing submodule)

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-importlib

My package looks something like this:

```
/mypackage
|-- __init__.py
|-- moduleA.py
|-- moduleB.py
|-- oldModule.py
```

And `__init__.py` looks something like this:

```
from mypackage.moduleA import abc
from mypackage.moduleB import jkl
```

This allows users to simply code as follows:

```
import mypackage as mpkg

mpkg.abc()
mpkg.jkl()
```

By default (using the above `import`) users have no access to functions in `oldModule.py`.
This is because 95% of users don't need that stuff (it's old).

---

For the 5% of users who need functions from the oldModule, they can write:

```
from mypackage.oldModule import xyz
xyz()
```

Many of these "oldModule" users don't need access to the functions imported by `__init__.py`

#### The problem is, when a user only does `from mypackage.oldModule import xyz`
 it is clear the the entire `__init__.py` is also being run.

Is there any way that I can either

- set it up so that `__init__.py` does not run if user does `from mypackage.oldModule import ...`, **or**
- can I **see** the structure of the import statement **from inside `__init__.py`**,
  so that I can detect that the user did `from mypackage.oldModule import ...`,
  and then I can use an `if` block inside `__init__.py` to decide which parts of the code to run **??**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do exactly what you're asking for. When you import `some_package.some_module`, the package always gets fully loaded before the submodule does.

But there might be some ways to mitigate the issues this causes in your case. If you want to avoid importing the `moduleA` and `moduleB` submodules when a user is looking for `oldModule`, you can perhaps make their loading lazy, rather than eager.

Starting in Python 3.7, [PEP 562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/) enables a module to have a function named `__getattr__` which will work like a method of the same name defined in a class. When an attribute of the module is looked up but not found, the `__getattr__` function will be called with the name.

So in your `__init__.py` file, you could do:

```
# from mypackage.moduleA import xyz   don't do these imports unconditionally any more
# from mypackage.moduleB import abc

def __getattr__(name):
    global xyz, abc
    if name == 'xyz':
        from .moduleA import xyz
        return xyz
    elif name == 'abc':
        from .moduleB import abc
        return abc
    raise AttributeError(f"module {__name__} has no attribute {name}")
```

If you have a lot more names you need to protect this way (not just two), you may want to write more general code that can process a list of names (probably one per sub-module) and import them properly using `importlib` and writing directly into the package's `__dict__`. That will be more convenient than trying to use `global` statements and writing a separate `if` branch for each name.

Comment: Thanks.   Will give that a try.